# Show second modal view controller after first was closed

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controller that opens modally. When the first VC closed then the second should be opened. But when I close the first one, the second one is not displayed at all.
what is the problem?

My code is:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        let flowVC = LanguageFlowViewController()
        self.present(flowVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Try `self.presentingViewController.present..`

Comment: Typically, you should let the previous VC decide what to do, using unwind segues, delegates or sth. else

Comment: Best practice would be indeed push that job back to previous VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open modally ThirdViewController after Dismiss SecondViewController then you have to create protocol for it.

Like we have three UIViewController(FirstViewController,SecondViewController and
ThirdViewController)

Step 1: We need to create a protocol in SecondViewController as given below code.

```
protocol DismissedViewProtocal {
    func dismissView()
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: DismissedViewProtocal?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func dismissSecondViewAction(_sender : AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.delegate?.dismissView()
    }        
}
```

Step 2: You need to add protocol in FirstViewController as given below

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DismissedViewProtocal {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func anAction(_sender : AnyObject){
            let flowVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
            secondVC?.delegate = self
            self.present(secondVC!, animated: true) {
            
            }
        }

    func dismissView() {
        let thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ThirdViewController")
            self.present(thirdVC!, animated: true) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This above peace of code will work. Please let me know if you are still getting some issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need reference of view controller from where you to present first view controller.

For example, you have view controller name as `X`, from there your first view controller `A` present. So you need reference of `X` to present `B`, because `A` will not be available in memory.

So when you try to present second view controller using `self`, it will do nothing.

So, for solution assign reference of `X` view controller to `A`. In class `A`, declare:

```
var refX: X?
```

While present `A` from `X`, set `self` to `refX`. Like:

```
var aVC = A() // This is temp, you need to instantiate your view controller here.
aVC.refX = self
self.present(aVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now, inside view controller `A`, when dismiss:

```
var bVC = B() // This is temp, you need to instantiate your view controller here.
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    if self.refX != nil {
        self.refX?.present(bVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: we already have 'presentingViewController' on the controller which is being presented, so what is the use of assigning references ?

Comment: @nikksindia, That's also good way, but there are also you need to take reference of `presentingViewController` inside presented view controller. Because when you try to get it in dismiss completion it will be nil. So on present, need to take reference and store `presentingViewController` inside it for later use.

Comment: Do like this and you might end up memory leak, since you are having strong reference to X

Comment: @SagarChauhan Reference to presentingViewController will not be nil at the time of completion but if you take reference of previous view controller, it can also cause memory problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your are dismissing the current view controller by calling `self.dismiss()`.
Therefore it is impossible for it to present anything anymore, since it is removed from the view hierarchy. As others have mentioned, try using the `self.presentingViewController` or `self.navigationController` (if it is on a navigationController) to present your new view.

However, if you need maximum flexibility create a delegate protocol. Create a protocol with a function `presentForChild(viewController: UIViewController)`. Before your previous view presents the view from which the code in your question belongs to, give it a reference of the protocol.

Example:

```
protocol ChildPresentDelegate: class {
    func presentForChild(vc: UIViewController)
}

class FirstController: UIViewController, ChildPresentDelegate {

    func presentForChild(vc: UIViewController) {
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    /**
     other code
     */

    func showControllerAsWasShownInTheQuestion() {
        let controller = SecondController()
        controller.delegate = self
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class SecondController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ChildPresentDelegate?

    func dismissMySelf() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            delegate?.presentForChild(vc: LanguageFlowViewController())
        }
    }
}
```